# Java == != && || operator?

Tags: java

I have a problem with my code. This code should check login and password. The problem is the else if statement showing a wrong output. Example, when i enter username == admin and password == 1234, it display username is incorrect.

```
import java.io.*;

public class login 
{
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
{
    String username = "admin"; 
    String password = "123";

    BufferedReader inData = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Enter username : ");
    username = inData.readLine();

    System.out.print("Enter password : ");
    password = inData.readLine();

    if((username == "admin") && (password == "123"))
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome " + username + "\n*** Login Sucessfully ***" + "\n*** Access Granted ***");
    }
    else if((username != "admin") && (password == "123"))
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, username is incorrect!\n*** Access Denied ***");
    }
    else if((username == "admin") && (password != "123"))
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, password is incorrect!\n*** Access Denied ***");
    }
    else if((username != "admin") && (password != "123"))
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, username and password is incorrect!\n*** Access Denied ***");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You understand the difference between == and equals when comparing strings right?

Comment: @Kero Kero  == are used for comparing int or float value (numbers), and .equals() method used for comparing String.

Comment: @AndrewL. Oh , never know before. Now i understand between == and .equals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.equals()` method is used to compare the string in this case.
 for e.g.  `username.equals("admin")` , it compares the variable username's value with the value "admin" , here both are Strings